# python 3 web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

python version: 
`Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

I am running below code it's working fine.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?otracker=categorytree&page=1&sid=tyy,4io").read()
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
result = bsObj
result.prettify()
nameList = result.findAll("a")
print(nameList)
for name in nameList:
    print(name.get_text())
```

result.prettify() is not beautify html code. Is there any problem with my code?

If i run below code i am getting below result.

result:

> ```
> [<div class="_2xw3j-" data-reactid="85"><div class="_3taVdZ" data-reactid="86"><div class="_2E-GO0" data-reactid="87"><d
> iv class="_CYfoo" data-reactid="88"><div class="row" data-reactid="89"><div class="col-5-12 HdKC4x _2jPfjn" data-reactid
> ="90"></div></div><div class="row" data-reactid="91"><div class="col-3-12 HdKC4x _2jPfjn" data-reactid="92"></div></div>
> </div></div></div></div>]
> ```

**code**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?otracker=categorytree&page=1&sid=tyy,4io").read()
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
result = bsObj
result.prettify()
g_data = result.findAll("div", {"class": "_3wU53n"})
print(g_data)
```

> expecting result like below:

Moto E3 Power (Black, 16 GB)  (2 GB RAM)

I want to get each mobile information from the website. Please help me with these.

Comment: you probably need to use the website's api (https://www.flipkart.com/api/3/), open inspector tools and inspect the network requests...

Comment: do you have any working example to get data through API?

Comment: looks like the api is a bit secured, but you can get around it just like the browser is(its working on client-side)

Comment: can i get data by using  web scrapping and using above code?

Comment: yes ofcourse but is just not good practice to parse html and take data out of it, you do that if there is no api around...

Comment: `{"class": "_3wU53n"}` you probably shouldn't use static class name, this class is prolly randomly generated on css/js obfuscation, try to be general about the dom tree you're getting the data with, and only use static tags/classes...